# `ng-repeat` for a dropdown with an array inside of an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Would like to do the following in the `ng-repeat` of a dropdown:

- Fetch from JSON the `categories` of the variable `product`
- Break down the `categories` array into new lines
- Filter with `unique`
- Display in dropdown

I have a demonstration at [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y6ZcZy86dBegsHlSYXEB?p=preview), and as you see, I've achieved the filter but I could not find a way to break the array and filter it.

My goal is to make a filter with the JSON requested and make a filter on the fly with the categories available.

Comment: In controller you need to map a new categories array by iterating products array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inject **`'angular.filter'`** to the controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
```

You actually do not need filter here, you can loop through the categories and add it to an array as follows

```
  $scope.filtered = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.products, function(key, value) {
    angular.forEach(key.categories, function(key, value) {
      if (!$scope.filtered.includes(key)) {
        $scope.filtered.push(key);
      }
    })
  })
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/q7u3p6N8afwMZnTXhcva?p=preview)**

Comment: My mistake! I was Ctrl + Zing and forgot it inside. Now it is working as it should!

Comment: CHECK THE UPDATED ANSWER